# How to calculate statistics for several sub-catchments (polygons) in the same time?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, statistics

I have a shapefile of groundwater management zone which is composed of 40 sub-catchments (40 polygons). I'd like to calculate the max., min. and mean elevation for each sub-catchment. Would you please let me know if there is any way to calculate all of these parameters (for all of the sub-catchments) using the shapefile and the DEM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

spatial analyst > zonal statistics as a table

In the environment, make sure that you use the same cell size for the analysis as with your DEM.
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//009z000000w8000000

Comment: I would also recommend that you have [Snap Raster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001w0000000m000000) environment set too, just  in case the catchment polygons were generated from some other dataset.